# How I do to mailmerge from a list in Microsoft Excel to >2 different types of PDF-templates?

Tags: excel, vba, adobe

**Hello everyone!**

---

I need help to find a fast and easy way to mailmerge data from Microsoft Excel to a PDF-template.

When I have only one type of PDF-template it was easy for me to follow this video when I use Javascript in Adobe Acrobat. This video also have a code to autosave the new PDF:s from data in Excel-list.

Link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqSkMgvNLSU&lc=UgzOz8yTWRnsUPAsgqh4AaABAg.9q2CnX_AarD9q2DkjuqbJP

---

Now I need your help! How I do when I have more than one PDF-template?
I realize that I now need to start from Excel instead. Excel mainly uses VBA code when creating a macro.

Below I have a example:
In Column A I present three types of templates *(Letter)* and the new names of files
for autosave need to be **Name**.pdf.

```
*Letter*    *Name*      *Age*   *Gift*
Grown       Johanna     45  
Child       Elias       10      Video game
Teen        Niclas      19      Car
Grown       Tiffany     35  
Child       Eric        8       Cellphone
Teen        Alexandra   18      Computer
Grown       Milo        31  
Child       Julia       12      Video game
Teen        Nina        15      Moped
```

---

Here are a example for the three different PDF-templates *(I make PDF-forms in Adobe Acrobat with a letter includes fields that I tag where text should be placed with data from the Excel list)*.

*Child:*
Hello **Name** my children! Today you be **Age** years old and you got a **Gift** as birthday gift from us.

*Teen:*
Hello my **Name**, you grow so fast and the years go by way too fast. Today you be **Age** years old and we will give you this **Gift** only for you.

*Grown:*
Hello **Name**, you are the best parent i have ever had. Today you be **Age** years old but you already have everything you could want! That's why we invite you to dinner instead.

I follow this video and works great for me when I have only one types of PDF-templates
and I use Javascript in Adobe Acrobat.

Link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqSkMgvNLSU&lc=UgzOz8yTWRnsUPAsgqh4AaABAg.9q2CnX_AarD9q2DkjuqbJP

---

Thank you very much for helping!
**Best regards from at1981 in Sweden.**

*I am a beginner in programming. But at my work, I have received new assignments that need to be solved and it is difficult when you cannot find what you are exactly looking for on Youtube, among other things.*

---

**Hello again!**

I have also try Google:
https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+mail+merge+data+from+Excel+to+bulk+of+PDF+when+I+have+two+different+templates&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=APwXEdcXOY4dg5TRYtJ8BbLJMaWhxj9enQ:1684910842756&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiexYqCro3_AhVcSvEDHTN5B0cQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=1075&dpr=1

But every solution I find on Google / Youtube is adapted to the fact that there is only one type of PDF-templates. *(In my example, I have three different kinds of PDF-templates.)*

Answer (score 0):

I got help form Chat GTP when I find out correct question to this AI-robot.

"
Sub MergeDocuments()

```
Dim WordApp As Object, TargetDoc As Object
Dim recordNumber As Long
Dim docType As String, fileName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, rngHeaders As Range, rngCell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1") ' Change to the name of your worksheet

' Open Word application
On Error Resume Next
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

WordApp.Visible = True ' Make Word visible

' Headers range in Excel (replace "Z" with your last column letter)
Set rngHeaders = ws.Range("C1:H1")

' For each row in the worksheet (starting from row 2 to avoid headers)
For recordNumber = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Get the document type
    docType = ws.Cells(recordNumber, "A").Value

    ' Choose the template based on the document type
    Select Case docType
        Case "Barn"
            Set TargetDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("H:\Dokument\Utveckling\Från Excel till PDF\Mall_Barn.docx")
        Case "Ungdom"
            Set TargetDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("H:\Dokument\Utveckling\Från Excel till PDF\Mall_Ungdom.docx")
        Case "Vuxen"
            Set TargetDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("H:\Dokument\Utveckling\Från Excel till PDF\Mall_Vuxen.docx")
        Case "Pensionar"
            Set TargetDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("H:\Dokument\Utveckling\Från Excel till PDF\Mall_Pensionar.docx")
    End Select

    ' Replace placeholders in the document with actual data
    ' This assumes you have placeholders like "<<Name>>", "<<Address>>" etc. in your Word document
    ' that match column names "Name", "Address" etc. in your Excel data.
    ' If your placeholders and data columns are named differently, adjust accordingly.
    
    For Each rngCell In rngHeaders
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(recordNumber, rngCell.Column)) Then
            With TargetDoc.Content.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = 1   'wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Execute FindText:="<<" & rngCell.Value & ">>", ReplaceWith:=ws.Cells(recordNumber, rngCell.Column).Value, Replace:=2   'wdReplaceAll
            End With
        End If
    Next rngCell

    ' Save the merged document as a PDF
    fileName = ws.Cells(recordNumber, "B").Value
    TargetDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        "H:\Dokument\Utveckling\" & fileName & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=17 ' 17 = wdExportFormatPDF

    ' Close the template without saving changes
    TargetDoc.Close False
Next recordNumber

' Close Word
WordApp.Quit

Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing
```

End Sub
"

Comment: Stack Overflow has a (temporary) ban on posting ChatGPT created content. https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy